"Time to display list of operating systems" in Windows unchecks itself
Issue
When I access SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe (or control 'sysdm.cpl,,3') > "Start-up and Recovery", and check "Time to display list of operating systems", then set its default accompanying value of 30s, its checkbox (and value) are immediately unset when I reload the window:

This is despite me having multiple EFI entries, including locally installed OSes.
Query
Consequently, how can I set it without it unsetting itself?
Potential Workaround
(Converted from cmd's .bat to pwsh's .PS1), stackoverflow.com/revisions/4710497/1 states:
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
#Requires -PSEdition 'Core'
#Requires -Version 7.5

If ([OperatingSystem]::IsWindows() -Eq $True) {
  $Timeout = Read-Host
  sudo bcdedit /timeout $Timeout
}

However, I've yet to test whether:

This actually does as the answer purports (the answer is fairly nondescript); and:
Its method of setting the value does not cause it to be unset, too.


I've not yet ascertained these because I'll be away from my PC for a few hours. Perhaps I should have asked this later, but I'd rather do it early and have more information available when I can get to this.
